# CodeIgniter - $this->input->post only returns a single value in array when multiple items were changed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying out CodeIgniter (I'm a novice coder) and am having some trouble with POST data from a form.

I have the following code to generate a form:

```html
<div>
 <?php echo form_open('todos/update_completed/'); ?>
 <?php foreach ($todos as $todo): ?>
  <?php echo form_checkbox('completed', $todo->id, $todo->completed); ?>
  <?php echo $todo->task; ?>
  <?php echo "<br />"; ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 <br />
 <?php echo form_submit('MySubmit', 'Update ToDos'); ?>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

This generates the following code:

```html
<form action="http://localhost:8091/index.php/todos/update_completed" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">


  <input name="completed" value="1" type="checkbox">Go to the shops
  <br>

  <input name="completed" value="2" checked="checked" type="checkbox">Pick up camera
  <br>

  <input name="completed" value="5" checked="checked" type="checkbox">Call Joey
  <br>

  <input name="completed" value="6" checked="checked" type="checkbox">Fill in tax return
  <br>

  <br>

  <input name="MySubmit" value="Update ToDos" type="submit">

</form>
```

When I try to retrieve the POST data using:

```html
$completed_todos = array(); 
$completed_todos[] = $this->input->post_get('completed');
```

... I allways get an array ($completed_todos) which only contains 1 (one) element - regardless how many checkboxes I checked, and it is always the latest checkbox I checked!

**print_r($completed_todos);** only returns the following: *Array ( [0] => 6 )*

Can someone please explain why I am not getting all the checkbox values returned in my array?

ps: I am following a tutorial from https://selftaughtcoders.com/creating-processing-form-codeigniter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are multiple CheckBoxes with same name you should write as below

Your Check Boxes

```
<input name="completed" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

Have to change the **name** like this `name="completed[]"`

```
<input name="completed[]" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="completed[]" value="2" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
<input name="completed[]" value="5" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
<input name="completed[]" value="6" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: I have seen this as a possible solution, but when using **<?php echo form_checkbox('completed', $todo->id, $todo->completed); ?>** as instructed by the CodeIgniter framework, the brackets aren't added. Would this imply that there is a bug in the CodeIgniter code?

Comment: You can use plain HTML tags instead of using codeigniter form.

Comment: I have posted this question to the CodeIgniter forum to ask whether the **form_checkbox('completed', $todo->id, $todo->completed);** can be used for array values as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the checkboxes that is selected right?
So make small modifications in your view

```
<input name="completed[]" value="1" type="checkbox">Go to the shops
  <br>
  <input name="completed[]" value="2" checked="checked" type="checkbox">Pick up camera
  <br>
  <input name="completed[]" value="5" checked="checked" type="checkbox">Call Joey
  <br>
  <input name="completed[]" value="6" checked="checked" type="checkbox">Fill in tax return
  <br>
  <br>
  <input name="MySubmit" value="Update ToDos" type="submit">
```

Answer (score -1):

In your controller access the checked values using following code

```
if(isset($_POST['MySubmit']))
{
    $checkbox_value=$_POST['completed'];
    var_dump($checkbox_value);
}
```